# Schema.org product title in offer

Tags: markup, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm implementing the Schema.org/Product mark-up in my e-commerce site. However my mark-up is set up in such a way that the itemprop="name" of the product lies inside of the offer (because of the link to the offer). Now to fix this I could use a display:none but that just seems like it is not the best solution. Is there a way to extract the name info about a product out of the offers section or should I change my mark-up?

Cheers,
Adnan

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img src="imageurl" itemprop="image" />
    <h1 class="product_brand" itemprop="brand manufacturer">Brand</h1>

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<div class="product_title"><a itemprop="url" href="link"><span itemprop="name">Product name</span></a><span id="stockcount"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">Product Availability</span></link></div>
<div class="product_price" itemprop="price">Price</div>
<link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
</div>

<div style="display: none">
<span itemprop="name">Product name (again)</span>
</div>

<div class="description" itemprop="description">
some description
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `meta` tag.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img src="imageurl" itemprop="image" />
    <h1 class="product_brand" itemprop="brand manufacturer">Brand</h1>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="product_title"><a itemprop="url" href="link"><span itemprop="name">Product name</span></a><span id="stockcount"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">Product Availability</span></link></div>
        <div class="product_price" itemprop="price">Price</div>
        <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
    </div>

    <meta itemprop="name" content="Product name" />

    <div class="description" itemprop="description">some description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought meta tags where only allowed in the head but that's incorrect!

Comment: That was true with HTML 4.1. In html5 you can use the meta tag in the body when the attribute `itemprop` is present. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element